# How to solve my Laravel between query on same column name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-4

I am a big beginner, i did so many research, and im struggling with this for 3 days now.

I beg you guys please help me

Please i beg you guys help me

```
I have a ManyToMany relation

public function measurement()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Measurement', 'users_measurement')->withPivot('value');
    }
```

**My search query**

```
 ->whereHas('measurement', function($q) use ( $from, $to )
        {
              foreach (array_combine($from, $to) as $f => $t) 
              {
                    if(!empty($f) && !empty($t))
                    {
                        $q->whereBetween('users_measuement.value', array($f, $t));
                    }
                }
        })
```

**Relation table**

```
user_id | measurement_id | value 
2       | 1              | 165 cm
2       | 2              | 48 kg
1       | 1              | 150 cm
1       | 2              | 35 kg
```

And i would like this to work with more then one between with different values in the same colum

Example returned form Laravel debug

```
lara_users_measurement`.`value` between 151 cm and 155 cm and `lara_users_measurement`.`value` between 35 kg and 52 kg
```

Please help iv been struggling with this for 3 days now :(

**Edited: more details**

**The form**

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'users/results', 'method' => 'GET', 'class' => 'ui form')) }}
                <div class="four fields">
                    <div class="field">
                      <label>Vezetéknév</label>
                      <input name="first_name" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                      <label>Keresztnév</label>
                      <input name="last_name" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                      <label>Felhasználónév</label>
                      <input name="username" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                      <label>Helység</label>
                      <input name="location" id="location" type="text">
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="three fields">
                    <div class="field">
                      <label>Neme</label>
                      <select name="gender" id="" class="form-select">
                        <option value="">Összes</option>
                        <option value="1">Férfi</option>
                        <option value="2">Nő</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                      <label>Tag fiók típusa</label>
                      <select name="account" id="account" class="form-select">
                        <option value="">Fiók típus kiválasztása</option>
                         @foreach($accounts as $account)
                            <option value="{{ $account->id }}">{{ $account->name }}</option>
                         @endforeach
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                     <label>Munka típus</label>
                      <select name="genres[]" id="genres" class="form-select-multiple" multiple>
                         @foreach($genres as $genre)
                            <option value="{{ $genre->id }}">{{ $genre->name }}</option>
                         @endforeach
                      </select>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div id="measurements-form">
                     <h3>Méretek és egyéb információ</h3>
                        @foreach($measurements as $measurement)
                            <div class="search-fields">
                                <label for="{{ $measurement->id }}">{{ $measurement->name }}</label>
                                <div class="two-fields">
                                  <select name="{{ 'from['.$measurement->id.']' }}" id="{{ $measurement->id }}" >
                                  <option value="">{{ $measurement->name  }} (tól)</option>
                                      @foreach(unserialize($measurement->value) as $value)
                                        <option value="{{ $value }}">{{ $value }}</option>
                                      @endforeach
                                  </select>

                                  <select name="{{ 'to['.$measurement->id.']' }}" id="{{ $measurement->id }}" >
                                  <option value="">{{ $measurement->name  }} (ig)</option>
                                      @foreach(unserialize($measurement->value) as $value)
                                        <option value="{{ $value }}">{{ $value }}</option>
                                      @endforeach
                                  </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach  
                 </div>
                 <div class="clearfix"></div>
                 {{ Form::submit('Keres', array('class' => 'ui orange small button')) }}
                {{ Form::close() }}
            </div>
```

**Results Controller**

```
 function __construct(User $user, Comment $comment, Account $account, Genre $genre, Measurement $measurement)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        $this->comment = $comment;

        $this->account = $account;

        $this->genre = $genre;

        $this->measurement = $measurement; 
    }

public function results()
    {

       $first_name = Input::get('first_name');
       $last_name = Input::get('last_name');
       $gender = Input::get('gender');
       $location = Input::get('location');
       $genre = Input::get('genres');
       $from = Input::get('from');
       $to = Input::get('to');


       $users = $this->user
       ->where('username', 'LIKE',  '%'.Input::get('username').'%')
       ->where('account_id', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('account').'%')
       ->whereHas('profile', function($q) use ( $first_name, $last_name, $gender, $location )
        {
            $q->where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%'.  $first_name )
               ->where('last_name', 'LIKE', '%'.  $last_name )
               ->where('gender', 'LIKE', '%'.  $gender )
               ->where('location', 'LIKE', '%'.  $location .'%' );

        })
        ->whereHas('genre', function($q) use ( $genre )
        {
            if(isset($genre))
            {
                $q->whereIn('genre_id', $genre );
            }

        })
         ->whereHas('measurement', function($q) use ( $from, $to )
        {
              foreach (array_combine($from, $to) as $f => $t) 
              {
                    if(!empty($f) && !empty($t))
                    {
                        $q->orWhereBetween('users_measurement.value', array($f, $t));
                    }
                }
        })
       ->where('approved', '=', 1)
       ->where('activated', '=', 1)
       ->paginate(15);

       $users->appends(Input::except('_token'))->links(); 

       $this->layout->title = 'Tagok';
       $this->layout->content = View::make('user::user/index')->with('users', $users);
    }
```

Comment: Please help me whit this logic, i swear i will transfer all of my points to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is `orWhereBetween` instead of `whereBetween` and wrapped in `where` closure (adding nested where clause):

```
->whereHas('measurements', function ($q) use ($from, $to) {
  $q->where(function($q) use ($from, $to) {
    foreach (array_combine($from, $to) as $f => $t)
    {
      if(!empty($f) && !empty($t))
      {
        $q->orWhereBetween('users_measurement.value', array($f, $t));
      }
    } 
  });
})
```

I'm not getting into, whether this code is good or not, but this will do the job for you.

Comment: that gives back false results, it returns all results from my db, but thank you for your answer

Comment: No, it doesn't. Show the query you'd like to execute, and rest of your code. If you have another `wheres` there, then you need to wrap those `orWhereBetweens` as nested ORs, if you know what I mean. You didn't make an effort to show expected output, so it's guessing.

Comment: Yeah do so, and in order to save yourself some time paste whole code, and I'll tell you what you need.

Comment: It's good. Just to clarify, you wanted all the users having ANY of the from-to measurements, or all the measurements?

Comment: from to measurements, i am building a modeling agency site, and this would serve a search query where there can search models, based on between height and weight, and i tested it with orWhereBetween, its not working, gives back all the results from the db no matter what value i chose

Comment: Yeah, this is what I meant by nested where. You need that piece of code like in my edit. Otherwise you have sth like: `where fk=pk and field=value OR anotherField=anotherValue` which breaks the `fk=pk` constraint

Comment: I think i love you now from the deep bottom of my heart, it works like a charm, thank you so much, really so much, for taking the time, and pushing effort in my question